# OnChangeText is not defined on - how can i resolve this error?

Tags: expo

Link to my codes (i cant embed images yet) https://i.stack.imgur.com/4XLgU.png

Im trying to add a TextInput Box to my screen but there is an error please tell me how i can resolve it.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

Create the two functions and the state for the text and number, please add the below code in your Caloriscreen Class.

```js
const [text,setText] = useState()
const [number, setNumber] = useState()

const onChangeText = (e) =>{
setText(e.target.value)
}

const onChangeNumber= (e) =>{
setNumber(e.target.value)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use onChangeText prop properly.
Let's say if we have a state property number which can be created as follows:

```
constructor(){
    super()
    this.state={
         number:0 }}
```

And now that you want to store the number user enters in input box you'll have to write:

```
<TextInput
onChangeText={(text)=>{
this.setState({
  number:text 
})}}/>
```